# TypeScript and File upload types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to set the types for a file upload, but I can not believe I have to define every single property on the file object

```
export type FileProps = {
  path: string 
  lastModified: number
  slice: () => void
  stream: () => void
  text: () => void
  arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer
  name: string
  size: number
  type: string
}

const [files, setFiles] = useState<FileProps[]>([])
```

I upload a few files and store them on the state, but then when I try to add to the form

```
const formData = new FormData()

for (const file of files) {
  formData.append('files', file)
}
```

I get an error on file

[image]

Comment: I think you want to use `file.text` if that is a string representation of the text of the file. You could also convert the `ArrayBuffer` to Blob or use the stream to create the blob.

Comment: I need to get the whole `file` with with name, size etc. as I am passing the file to the back end, it works if I turn every type to `any` but I get the yellow warning, there must be a better way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just use `File`, then you get exactly what you want:

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState<File[]>([])

const formData = new FormData()

for (const file of files) {
  formData.append('files', file)
}
```

That should get you all the fields documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVAsAFBv0QB2q8A2iWAAbdKgA0cDDABiw0QF04AXhQZsedAB5ZIvvIB8ACj0BKNh269S0EABE8OZXC7oA7nGk37uQ2fasSaDhDTh54QRE4CBJSOVQTRDY4ayg7BwA6HDAwdC4AE0MqCNEqCWK-QnNWIA)

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the `FormData.append` method is Blob or USVString.

You had mentioned in a comment that the entire structure needs to be sent to the backend. So, you need to convert the FormData instance to a blob.

```
for (const file of files) {
  formData.append('files', new Blob([JSON.stringify(file)], {type : 'text/html'});)
}
```

Comment: I get `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BlobPart[] | undefined'.`

Comment: Answer edited. The blob constructor needs a type of an array.