# Handle File Validation Using Yup and React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, react-hook-form, yup

So, basically, I have a form where I have `<input type="file" />` as one of the fields. I want this field to be required.

```
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
  defaultValues,
  resolver: yupResolver(schema),
});

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <input type="text" {...register("fullname")} />
  <input type="file" {...register("image")} />
</form>
```

I have used yup for validation schema:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  fullname: yup.string().required("Name is required"),
  image: yup.mixed().required("Image is required"),
})
```

And, I have my defaultValues as:

```
const defaultValues: {
  name: string,
  image: File | null,
} = {
  name: "",
  image: null,
}
```

If I do this, I get an error saying

> Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.

I think the reason is that schema is not allowing the image to be null whereas in the defaultValues, I am initially setting my image field to be null. However, If I set the image field as nullable, the validation won't work as it means that the file can be empty, but I do not want it to throw an error when the field is empty.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The file will have an array of file objects so you need to make the image type File[] or the default value would be an empty array and for validation, you can just put a check on the empty array.

FYR, you can [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68214379/typescript-and-file-upload-types) here for proper image type